# Can we have a catch all question for marketing a website / blog other than SEO?

Tags: discussion

There is a catch all question to [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) .

Can we have a catch all question for marketing a website / blog other than SEO? Here I am expecting that ways to promote bog/website other than SEO. I mean Adwords, Facebook Marketing, Reddit ,etc with explanation for each each point.

**Sample Questions :**

[What is the best way to promote a programming blog?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8189/what-is-the-best-way-to-promote-a-programming-blog)

[How to promote a new social network?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/how-to-promote-a-new-social-network)

[How effectively to promote\publicize my web application?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/how-effectively-to-promote-publicize-my-web-application)

[Does social networking really help promote a site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68547/does-social-networking-really-help-promote-a-site)

[how to promote a web app?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-to-promote-a-web-app)

**Proposed Question :** How to promote a website (Other than SEO)? or  How to get traffic to website other than SEO traffic? (I am bad at Engish, So I think other user can suggest good topic).

Comment: Can you suggest a specific title for this question and list some recently asked questions that would be marked duplicate of it rather than be closed as off-topic?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Updated the question...

Comment: I'm torn on this one. It is an obvious off-topic yet frequently asked question. But I see this becoming spam fest.

Comment: @JohnConde All the more reason to have the catch all question. Then close the catch all as *off topic* and close all future questions as a dupe of the catch all. Comments on the catch all can elucidate the off topic nature and give alternatives.

Comment: I almost think it's better to allow more general marketing/seo questions even if there is some duplicate content. You'll get a lot more responses and activity on the site. More good answers could get more search traffic. And since marketing a website/product through SEO is such a highly sought after topic on the internet, I would encourage these discussions rather than mark them all as duplicate. There's a lot of SEO leaders with many, many blog posts about how to do better SEO on websites. A lot of those pages have very similar ideas and content, yet rank so well.That's just my thoughts.